# MapBinder not available in Guice 3.0

Tags: java, guice

This is rather strange that the MapBinder is not included in my Gucie 3.0 obtained from Maven repository:

My maven config is like:

```
<dependencies>
    ....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

My Guice 3.0 in the maven repository does not even have the package:

```
com.google.inject.multibindings
```

Can someone please point me out to the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the multibindings module - it's part of the extensions:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```